# JavaFX FXML - Add choices to choice box

Tags: java, javafx

I am having a very tough time finding any documentation, so sorry in advance for the dumb question.  I would like to populate a choice box that's declared with FXML with items that that are part of an ArrayList.

Here is my FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?> <?import javafx.scene.control.*?> <?import java.lang.*?> <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="application.LMUController">   <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="600.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="551.0" />   </columnConstraints>   <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="346.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="222.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="316.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="178.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />   </rowConstraints>    <children>
      <GridPane>
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="312.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="443.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="443.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label contentDisplay="TOP" text="List Price" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label contentDisplay="TOP" text="City" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label contentDisplay="TOP" text="Address" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label contentDisplay="TOP" text="Comps CSV" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
            <FlowPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <TextField prefWidth="308.0" />
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
            <FlowPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <ChoiceBox id="choiceCity" prefWidth="150.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="8.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </ChoiceBox>
                  <Button id="btnCitiesRefresh" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Refresh" onAction="#btnCitiesRefresh_action">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="8.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button id="btnLmuPreview" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preview" />
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
            <FlowPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="btnListPrice" prefWidth="150.0" />
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
            <FlowPane prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="279.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="txtCompsCSVPath" editable="false" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="8.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Button id="btnCompsCSVBrowse" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse" />
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <GridPane GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets right="8.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="91.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="89.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="61.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="39.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <FlowPane prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="592.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                <Button id="btnSaveExcel" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Export to Excel">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="8.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>    </children> </GridPane>
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
package application;

import java.awt.Choice;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.input.InputEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import localMarketUpdate.*;

public class LMUController implements Initializable{

    LMUParser lmuParser;
    ChoiceBox choiceCity;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        lmuParser = new LMUParser();

    }

    @FXML
    private void btnCitiesRefresh_action(ActionEvent event)
    {
        ArrayList<String> cities = lmuParser.getCities();
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cities);


        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++){

            list.add(i, cities.get(i));
            //list.add(i, cities.get(i));

        }

        choiceCity.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One","Two","Three"));
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on the line:

```
choiceCity.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One","Two","Three"));
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   application.LMUController.btnCitiesRefresh_action(LMUController.java:47)
>     ... 58 more

The ultimate goal here is to have the ChoiceBox by populated with the items in the ArrayList.  How is this accomplished, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done like this:

```
ArrayList<String> cities = lmuParser.getCities();
ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cities);
choiceCity.setItems(list);
```

However for this to work the `ChoiceBox` actually has to be injected, which is not happening since you use the `id` attribute that assigns the `Node`'s id property instead of using the `id` attribute from the fxml namespace. Also it would be a good idea to use a type parameter of `ChoiceBox` and use the `private` modifier:

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> choiceCity;
```

FXML file:

add the namespace prefix of the fxml namespace to the id attribute of the `ChoiceBox`:

```xml
...
<ChoiceBox fx:id="choiceCity" prefWidth="150.0">
...
```